# Proving $x=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ is the key root to solve $x^4-2(a+b)x^2+(a-b)^2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Proving the roots of

> $$x^4-2(a+b)x^2+(a-b)^2=0$$
>   are...... 
>   $$x=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$$
>   $$x=\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$$
>   $$x=-\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$$
>   $$x=-\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$$
>   When $a$ and $b$ are  real numbers(negative or positive)

I  proved this by substituting $x=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ in the main equation , but I think this way not effective because  It needs to be repeated four times to complete the proving.

Is there another effective proving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $r$ and $s$ are solutions to your equation, then we consider $r^2$ and $s^2$:
$$r^2+s^2=2(a+b)$$
and
$$r^2s^2=(a-b)^2$$
These simultaneous equations can be solved fairly easily, giving us two similar formulas, with a $\pm$, for $r^2$ and $s^2$. Taking square roots gives your four solutions, with another $\pm$. All this shows why the solutions are so similar in form, with two plus-or-minuses.

Answer (score 5):

since
$$(x^2-a-b)^2=4ab\Longrightarrow x^2=a+b\pm 2\sqrt{ab}=(\pm\sqrt{a}\pm \sqrt{b})^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the determinant:$$4(a+b)^2-4(a-b)^2 = 16ab$$
Then find the roots as following:
$$x^2 = \frac{2(a+b)+\sqrt{16ab}}{2},\frac{2(a+b)-\sqrt{16ab}}{2}$$
$$x^2 = a+b+2\sqrt {ab}, a+b-2\sqrt {ab}$$
$$x = \pm(\sqrt a + \sqrt b), \pm(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to verify this with minimal computations is to expand the product $P(x) = \prod (x\pm\sqrt{a}\pm\sqrt{b})$ (where the product runs over all combinations of signs).

Taking as a variable $t_1 = x+\sqrt{a}$ and $t_2 = x-\sqrt{a}$, this becomes

$$P(x) = (t_1 + \sqrt{b})(t_1-\sqrt{b})(t_2 + \sqrt{b})(t_2-\sqrt{b}) = (t_1^2 - b)(t_2^2 - b).$$

Now $t_1t_2 = x^2-a$ and $t_1^2 + t_2^2 = 2(x^2 + a)$. So

$$P(x) = (x^2-a)^2 - 2b(x^2+a) + b^2 = x^4 - 2(a+b)x^2 +a^2 - 2ab + b^2. $$

This being said, the from math110's answer is nicer. In fact if you read it like this, it is even more obvious.

$$ \begin{aligned} x = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} & \overset{\mathrm{square}}\implies x^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2\sqrt{ab} \\ &\overset{\mathrm{rewrite}}\implies x^2 - a^2 - b^2 = 2\sqrt{ab} \\ &\overset{\mathrm{square}}\implies (x^2-a^2-b^2)^2 = 4ab. \end{aligned}$$